# XCode 4.3.2 iOS 5.1.1 app crash at launch time

Tags: crash, code-signing, jailbreak

I've done the edit on the `SDKSettings.plist`. did the don't code sign thing and I can build the project. it installs perfectly on my jailbroken device (with no error); but when I wanna run it, it jumps out of the app immediately! (crash at runtime)
I've installed the same app with the same file on another iPod Touch running iOS 5.0 and it works perfectly. so the problem seems to be with the 5.1.1 version. (iGuess)
I have NO IDEA how to make this work.
any ideas?

Comment: you are still fake code-signing, though, right?  for example, with `ldid -S MyApp.app/MyApp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use [JailCoder](http://www.jailcoder.com).

Answer (score 0):

I've been all up and down this problem and I think I have your solution.  Yes, you have to have a minimal level of fake code signing if you want to deploy and debug from Xcode 4.3. Turn code signing back on in Xcode and follow the basic instructions [here](http://androidnirvana.comule.com/wordpress/2012/05/building-apps-for-ios-5-1-with-xcode-4-3-2-without-code-signing-and-developer-provisioning-profile/). Don't worry about the -gta code signing flag and use the following for your ldid3.py script (the other one won't work at all):

```
!/usr/bin/python
from sys import argv
from subprocess import call, check_call
from os.path import basename, splitext, join
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile

app = argv[-1]
obj_path = join(app, splitext(basename(app))[0])
with NamedTemporaryFile() as f:
    f.write("""
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>get-task-allow</key>
    <true/>
  </dict>
</plist>\n""")
    f.flush()
    check_call(['/usr/local/bin/ldid', '-S' + f.name, obj_path])
```

I didn't have to do the tdmtanf step, but that may be because I have appsync installed.

Comment: thanks, but I already found the EASIEST solution. check out my answer below!